# How to get the value of dynamic created control before page load in ASP.NET c#

Tags: javascript, c#, css, sql, asp.net

How to get the value of dynamic created control before page load in ASP.NET c#

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    //createDynamicControl(i);
    var elems = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(key => key.Contains("lb_")).ToList();

    foreach (string key  in elems)
    {
        this.createDynamicControl(i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

This code is not working in my case.

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

You are close. You get the value with `Request.Form[key]`.

```
foreach (string key in elems)
{
    Response.Write("Control '" + key + "' has the value of '" + Request.Form[key] + "'<br>");
}
```